# V-if statement only for one line/link

Tags: javascript, vue.js, if-statement, vue-component, vue-router

I try to hide a link("myprofile") below a picture, when the if-statement isn't "right", in VUE.JS.
But when I set the v-if into the vue-router or div tag, the whole picture/div-tag is hidden.
How can I set a if-statement, which only concerns the link?

The Code:

```
            <router-link v-if="condition == true" class="nav-link" to="/myprofile">
              <div
                class="img"
                :style="{
                  'background-image': "url"
                }"
              />
            </router-link>
```

Comment: you can't. destroying the parent will destroy all its children

Answer (score 0):

Just add another `img div` and use with `v-else`

```
       <router-link v-if="condition == true" class="nav-link" to="/myprofile">
          <div
            class="img"
            :style="{
              'background-image': "url"
            }"
          />
        </router-link>
        <div
            v-else
            class="img"
            :style="{
              'background-image': "url"
            }"
          />
```

Answer (score 0):

**you can define tow templates like this**

```
<template v-if="condition == true">
 <router-link  class="nav-link" to="/myprofile">
          <div
            class="img"
            :style="{
              'background-image': "url"
            }"
              />
     </router-link>
</template>
<template v-else>
    <div
      class="img"
          :style="{
            'background-image': "url"
                }"
              />
</template>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the component using a dynamic component and `v-bind:is` (https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#is):

```js
<component
  :is="condition ? 'router-link' : 'span'"
  class="nav-link"
  to="/myprofile"
>
  <div
    class="img"
    :style="{
      'background-image': "url"
    }"
  />
</component>
```